# Image Segmentation: Apply Binary Mask To Separate PV Panel Surface And The Soiling On Its Surface

Tags: python, data-annotations, image-segmentation

I'm quite new to image segmentation. I've a dataset of PV panel images. Here is an example image:

[image: Soiled PV Panel Surface]

I want the background to be the PV panel surface and the foreground to be the soiled portion of the PV panel surface. Then, I want to calculate the % area the soiled portion is covering the PV panel surface. I believe I will have to initially annotate my image dataset. Are there any free tools for it?

Can I achieve my goal using the semantic segmentation method? Thank you very much for your time. :)

Comment: Have you tried Super Annotate for Annotation? https://www.superannotate.com/

Comment: Not yet. Is it free?

Comment: Yes, you also have a free version. Check the pricing section.